# Splitting the text of a single cell and using it as source for a validation list without VBA

Tags: excel

Im trying for some hours already to split a text cell into a usable object to the validation list.

The cells today are populated by 3 or more (N) comma (I can change that to semicolons, pipes...) separated values like "1,2,3" or "5,test,8,new"

I want to transform that into a validation list with N different values.

In the following post there is a formula that splits a string into and array, but I have not managed to use it as source:
[Split a string (cell) in Excel without VBA (e.g. for array formula)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25316094/split-a-string-cell-in-excel-without-vba-e-g-for-array-formula/25316426)

Is it possible to create a Dynamic Range from splitting the cell text and feeding it into a 'combobox' (validation list).

Another similar example of what I am looking for but without VBA:
[Excel Dynamic Drop Down Using Comma Delimited Data](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28324004/excel-dynamic-drop-down-using-comma-delimited-data)

What am I doing wrong here? Thanks for reading this far.

Comment: AFAIK you'll actually have to put the values in separate cells. Using a formula in a validation won't result in three different selectable values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this by

- Use a formula to break up the comma separated list into separate cells
- Then use dynamic range names to refer to the DV List

### Formula

to return an array in the sequence of {1,99,198,297, ...}

Create a defined name formula:  (Formulas --> define name)

```
seq_99   Refers To: =IF(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))=1,1,(ROW(INDEX($1:$65535,1,1):INDEX($1:$65535,255,1))-1)*99)
```

With your lists in row 1 on some worksheet, use the following formula:

```
A2: =INDEX(TRIM(MID(SUBSTITUTE(A$1,",",REPT(" ",99)),seq_99,99)),ROWS($1:1))
```

and fill down as far as needed to account for your longest list.  I assumed `A2:A10` would be sufficient.

[image]

Next, create dynamic named formulas to refer to just the portion of each list that contains data.

Example:

```
dvList1 Refers to:  =OFFSET(Sheet2!$A$1,1,0,COUNTA(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10)-COUNTBLANK(Sheet2!$A$1:$A$10)-1)
```

Format your DataValidation cell as a List with the named formula:

[image]

The list will now show the non-blank entries.

Comment: It's not possible to do it without populating this new rows with the formula? I can't obtain the list directly?

Comment: @MBarni That is correct, considering that you have precluded the use of VBA.

Answer (score 1):

It is possible to formulate this using `Find`. To split the text in cell "A1", the formula will be:

- 1<sup>st</sup> part - cell B1 formula:

  `=LEFT(A1,FIND(",",A1)-1)`
- 2<sup>nd</sup> part - cell C1 formula:

  `=MID(A1,FIND(",",A1)+1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1)+1)-FIND(",",A1)-1)`
- 3<sup>rd</sup> part - cell D1 formula:

  `=MID(A1,FIND(",",A1,FIND(",",A1)+1)+1,999999)`

Then a list validation may be added to Cell E1, with the range `B1:D1`
[image]

Comment: It's not possible to do it without populating this new columns with the formula? I can't obtain the list directly?

Comment: hi MBarni, thats right, the list can't be obtained directly as excel data validation accepts either a list or a formula - but not both